# Android Send MMS programticaly?

Tags: android, mms

I am trying to send mms grammatically this is my code

```
ntent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            //sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
            sendIntent.putExtra("address", sendingnumbeer);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Sample");   
            File dir = new File("/sdcard/VinstantMessage/");

            String path=dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/abc.mp4";
            File fl=new File(path);
            if(fl.exists()){
                System.out.println("file is exist");
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fl);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sendIntent.setType("video/*"); 
            sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           // getApplicationContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
            startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1);
```

it is opening the send mms window but i am unable to get user clicked on send mms or not ? how i can check this

Thanks

Comment: "I am unable to get user clicked on send mms or not?" — What do you mean, I don't understand.

Comment: after clicked on send button onactivity result not working ? that is my mean

Answer (score 0):

OK i have resolved the issue i was adding the     "sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);"

Remove this line and it will working good

thanks